# How to find Sharepoint Library Metadata in the SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Working on migrating documents out of the document library and into a different system and I want to export out of the SQL server the metadata associated with the documents into the new system.

I'm using SQL Management Studio and HIEDISQL to look and find these records but I cant find them anywhere via searching.

This is SQL server 2008 running Sharepoint 2010.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have googled a lot for the last week and have not been able to come up with anything since Google is trying to be smarter than my "exact phrase" searches so its been pretty frustrating :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, but ended up using the [.Net Client Side Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx).  Pluralsight has some excellent [training videos](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=sp2010-development&highlight=sahil-malik_sp2010-client-object-model#sp2010-client-object-model) on this.  I'm not certain but I think the actual storage structure for the metadata is in a varbinary or some other sort of blob field, so it might not even be feasible to access by direct query.  Also, direct querying of the sharepoint database could void your support agreement with MS.

Hope this helps...